# Best way to import large excel file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, pentaho, bcp

We are trying to devise an optimal method for importing very large Excel files into SQL database.  Using SSIS is somewhat troublesome because it scans top X records to determine the format of the file, but rows further down may be different, so it takes a lot of trial and error, with us having to bring the unusual columns to the top so SSIS can "learn".

When we get new file formats to import, they conform to specification in terms of row formatting etc - so we can say we know the schema in advance.  The SQL destination tables have the same schema, with couple of extra columns such as date inserted and original filename.

Is there an easier way to create format definitions for new files we are going to insert? We don't have to use SSIS, we are open to any other tool, with a view for as much automation as possible. There's a question of testing the sanity of data we will import, we were planning on doing basic queries against staging datasets such as "less than 1% of records can miss postal code" etc.

Many thanks

Comment: Is it compulsory that the file be in Excel? If you could export to CSV, you could use BCP to import the entire line to a single record in a staging table, then run a Stored Proc on that to check for errors, and the "learning" part you mention above. Then you can think about automating it pretty easily from there.

Comment: There is a server-level setting that tells SSIS how many rows to scan to determine the format of the file.  I forget the name of the setting, but I'm sure it can be easily googled.

Comment: @TabAlleman is correct, you can use TypeGuessRows=0 (https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/imex1-revisit-and-typeguessrows-setting-change-to-0-watch-for-performance/), however there may be performance issues with a large file since it will scan the whole thing.  I would suggest pursuing getting the file into a delimited format.  Most systems will export to more than just excel.

Comment: Both BCP and SSIS suggestions point us in the right direction - many thanks everyone

Comment: You could also use a script task and read everything in the file as text, instead of using an Excel source. Format it appropriately in later tasks. Also IMEX = 1 can be used to read data for mixed formats

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import data as text and after that you can convert that using Derived Column transformation. You can read data from Excel as Text using IMEX option in Connection String. More information about this parameter you can find [here](http://dougbert.com/blog/post/importing-from-excel-imex-and-mixed-data-types.aspx).